# How to receive message from socket room in angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

This is the server code which I write using node js and socket io. Here I create a room and broadcast a message to all user except the sender in a particular room.

#### server.js

```
    var io = require('socket.io');
var server = http.createServer().listen(8081);
var socket = io.listen(server);

var roomno = 1;
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 
    
    client.on('join', function(data) {
        client.join(data.room);  //join in socket room
        console.log(data.user + ' joined in room '+ data.room);
        client.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('new_user_joined',{user : 
        data.user,message :'jas join this room'});
    });
    
});
```

#### chat.service.ts

```
export class ChatService {
 constructor(private socket: Socket) { }
  joinRoom(data){
  this.socket.emit('join', data);
 }

 newUserJoined() {
   return this.socket.fromEvent('new_user_joined').pipe(map(data => 
   data));
  }

}
```

#### app.component.ts

```
join(){
this.service.joinRoom({user : this.name,room : 'hall'});

this.service.newUserJoined().subscribe(
    result => {
      this.respObj=result;
    }
   );
  }
```

In the above code I broadcast a message to a particular room in socket and try to receive this message from angular. But I don't get this message from app.component.ts